# SpamFlavor is not defined for radio box

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working my way thru Knockout and Is having some problems with the radio button.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: currentQuestion">
    <p data-bind="text: question"></p>
    <p>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
    </p>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.nextQuestion">Next</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.currentQuestion = ko.observable();
        self.spamFlavor = ko.observable();
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The message is: `Message: spamFlavor is not defined`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi Jason, couple of things. 1)If your KO ViewModel is declared in a separate js file, make sure you included it in the js references. 2) Is the html you provided inside a hierarchical html. When you bind KO to something inside a hierarchy, you will not be in the scope of the viewModel. So, you might have to do something like $parent.spamFlavor or $root.spamFlavor depending on what your html hierarchy is set up as. If you think its set up properly, could you paste your html in there.

Comment: Hello Krishna Teja Veeramachaneni! I have extended my code above a bit. Still the same problem. If I remove spamFlavor from HTML and JS (with binding too) it works fine. But as soon as I try to data-bind those radio buttons I get the error statet above

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and is working. It could be that the browser is caching an older version of the javascript?

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.spamFlavor = ko.observable();
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yrj5okz1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are using "with" binding here. So, all the context inside that div will have the datacontext of that "with" related property (in this case..currentQuestion). So, instead, use this because spamFlavor is a property on ViewModel and not in currentQuestion object.

```
<div data-bind="with: currentQuestion">
    <p data-bind="text: question"></p>
    <p>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: $root.spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: $root.spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: $root.spamFlavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
    </p>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.nextQuestion">Next</button>
</div>
```

Or even easier (assuming you are NOT loading the "currentQuestion" data from somewhere asynchronously)

```
<div>
    <p data-bind="text: currentQuestion.question"></p>
    <p>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
    </p>
    <button data-bind="click: nextQuestion">Next</button>
</div>
```

You don't really need a with statement in this case in my opinion unless you plan to have more stuff in there later.